# Reuse Bitmap in CreateBitmap

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, textures

Can i use reused bitmap for when creating a bitmap. Here is my current code. It shows memory out of error. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            progress++;
            float scale =(float) progress/5;
            int width = textureBitmap.getWidth();
            int height = textureBitmap.getHeight();
            float scaleWidth = ((float) width*scale) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) height*scale) / height;
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            //BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inBitmap=croppedBitmap;
            resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textureBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
            if(scaleWidth >=1 && scaleHeight >= 1)
            {
                croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resizedBitmap,0,0,width,height);
                if (resizedBitmap!= croppedBitmap) 
                    resizedBitmap.recycle();              
            }
            else
                croppedBitmap = resizedBitmap;
            try {
                if (clicked == 0)
                    renderer.changeTopTexture(croppedBitmap);
                if (clicked == 1)
                    renderer.changeHandTexture(croppedBitmap);
                if (clicked == 2)
                    renderer.changeNeckTexture(croppedBitmap);
            }
            catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "TEXTURE ERROR");
            }

        }
```

What am trying to do is scale the texture of a model on seekbar change. Any alternative ideas are also welcomed.

Comment: Why is my question demoted???

Comment: I believe this is a great question! but you posted a lot of unrelated code

Answer (score -1):

You can get idea from below examples,

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/drawing/blur_an_image_with_renderscript/

https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur